# C++ How an binary serialization through an socket (TCP)

Tags: c++, c, sockets

sorry for my bad English.

The Context :

I have 6 variables

1. unsigned char
2. char
3. unsigned short
4. int
5. int
6. int

I serialize this data for prepare the send to socket.

The problem, how can i store my serialized data and send it ?

My first solution, use an structure for send my data but this solution requires a cast and the cast action is very slow.

Have you better solution than store my variable in structure ?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>

typedef int SOCKET;
typedef struct sockaddr_in SOCKADDR_IN;
typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;

#define PORT 4241
template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& raw_write(std::ostream &os, const T &t)
{
  return os.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&t), sizeof t);
}

int main()
{
  char protocole;
  char id_module;
  unsigned short id_message;
  int id_client;
  int size_msg;
  unsigned long timestamp;

  SOCKET csock;
  SOCKADDR_IN csin;

  protocole = 1;
  id_module = 2;
  id_message = 256;
  id_client = 8569;
  size_msg = 145;
  timestamp = 1353793384;
  csock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  csin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  csin.sin_family = AF_INET;
  csin.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  connect(csock, (SOCKADDR*)&csin, sizeof(csin));
  raw_write(ss, protocole);
  raw_write(ss, id_module);
  raw_write(ss, id_message);
  raw_write(ss, id_client);
  send(csock, ss.str().c_str(), strlen(ss.str().c_str()), 0);
  close(csock);
```

}

Doesn't work because string contain '\0' and send cut it.

I said, cast is slow on many data send. At the receive i need to cast again for recovery my data.

This action is more slow than just bytes reading.

Comment: The cast action is slow? Since when?

Comment: The cast action on many packet. Make an benchmark on 100.000 packet

Comment: "the cast is slow"... The cast is *wrong*; slow has nothing to do with it. wire-transfer is all about packing and unpacking data in portable form. consider functions like `htons`, `htols`, etc. Develop a protocol, and *stick to it*.

Comment: That still doesn't make it slow. (Apart from it being the opposite of serialization, but that's a separate problem.)

Comment: Can you show us how you serialize and send your data and why you think the cast is the bottleneck? (update your question with it)

Comment: @WhozCraig [libpack](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libpack/) might be useful for that.

Comment: I don't understand, why you need a cast to use a struct ?

Comment: @melpomene dude! thanks for the link. I've not seen that lib before and will *definitely* check it out. much apprec.

Comment: Post edit, i need to cast my struct for send it by an socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I f you dont want to do it from scratch, you could use [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview). Its a strong library letting you define a protocol, which is nothing else but a class, that can (de)serialize itself to(from) a stream, file, buffer or string.

I use it myself, its nice to serialze it to a string which is easy to send via socket.

EDIT: Reply to comment:

Okay then notice that its not `send (...)` truncating your stream. Its c_str() which ends on a `'\0'`. Maybe you should try to avoid streams and use a container which offers access to its raw data like std::string or std::vector with `const void * data()`. You could pass this and `size()` to `send(...)`.

Comment: Yes, this lib is a good alternative but i need to made my own system.